# glVertexAttribPointer index for texture co-ordinates in OpenGL ES 3.0

Tags: android, opengl-es

Given this array in my example:

```
            private final float[] mVerticesData =
            {
                    -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f, // Position 0
                    0.0f,  0.0f,       // TexCoord 0
                    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, // Position 1
                    0.0f,  1.0f,       // TexCoord 1
                    0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, // Position 2
                    1.0f,  1.0f,       // TexCoord 2
                    0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f, // Position 3
                    1.0f,  0.0f        // TexCoord 3
            };
```

In the draw loop attributes are set:

```
    //Load the vertices
    mVertices.position ( 0 );

    GLES30.glVertexAttribPointer ( 0, 3, GLES30.GL_FLOAT,
            false,
            5 * 4, mVertices );

    // Load the texture coordinate
    mVertices.position ( 3 );

    GLES30.glVertexAttribPointer ( 1, 2, GLES30.GL_FLOAT,
            false,
            5 * 4,
            mVertices );
```

The loading of the vertices seems perfectly logical to me the position is zero which is the first element
in the buffer and there are three elements that make up the vertices vector. The stride then includes five
elements three for for the vertices vector and two for the texture co-ordinates so the I take (5*4) to be
a conversion to bytes I think.

My question is in regards to the loading of the texture co-ordinates I was expecting to see the index of
glVertexAttributePointer to be set to 0 however it is set to 1. Is it possible the texture co-ordinates are
read backwards by OpenGL? If not why is the index 1? I see that it works in this configuration but I don't understand the index of 1.

### My code in pastebin: http://pastebin.com/0hxDS8Kt

My shaders in pastebin: http://pastebin.com/8DkBfETn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was expecting to see the index of glVertexAttributePointer to be set
>   to 0 however it is set to 1.

The number is a simply a mapping of the symbol name (the text string) to a binding location (the numeric ID) which the rest of the driver understands. It doesn't really hold any semantic meaning other than that (i.e. it's not an address or pointer encoding).

Option one: The application is responsible for setting up the binding locations, either via application API call, or via setting a binding location in the shader source (which is new in OpenGL ES 3.0).

https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glBindAttribLocation.xml

Option two: The application can use driver assigned binding locations. No guarantee on order is provided - you have to query it:

https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGetAttribLocation.xml

In your case you are defining the binding values in the shader with this code sequence:

```
layout(location = 0) in vec4 a_position;          
layout(location = 1) in vec2 a_texCoord;
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand yet. As far as I can tell glVertexAttributePointer in my example is specifying the second column (if one starts counting from element 0 of the array). As far as I can tell neither of the functions that you are talking about here are used in the sample. There is some information about the application being responsible for setting up the binding locations and perhaps that is what is occurring. I think perhaps what you are saying is the binding can be manually applied with the function glBindAttribLocation.

Comment: The position ( 3 ) would be the first column of texture co-ordinates. Some how I would expect the glVertexAttributePointer thereafter that position( 3 ) is actually saying index 4 of the float buffer which is the second column of texture co-ordinate data not the first.

Comment: The numeric ID is not an address or column. It's a simply a mapping of the symbol name (the text string) to a binding location (the numeric ID) which the rest of the driver understands. You get two options - you can either assign the binding values yourself or you can use values provided by the driver. In your case you are defining the values yourself in the shader (answer updated).